# Ajax render partial view without server code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to JQuery so I might be asking something basic.
Is there a way to render a partial view in Js without involving any server code? My case scenario is that when the user clicks a search button I want to render a results list/panel on the same page.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: don't need ajax. Just have all the data located in json or javascript variables and create a function that searches through it.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax fundamentally requires that a server is involved. It means "making an HTTP request from JavaScript without leaving the page". You can't make an HTTP request without an HTTP server to make it to.

JavaScript is quite capable of [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) without involving a server.

Comment: Ok I phrased my question incorrectly. I want to write all my code in my .js file. How can i render a partial with Ajax inside my .js file? Thank you!

Comment: @R.P. — I refer you back to the answer.